Deploy a .net application to a EC2 instance
I am trying to deploy a .net 8.0 application to an EC2 AWS instance. The script is failing when it tries to copy the .zip file into the server.
name: Deploy .NET 8.0 to EC2 IIS Server via SCP

on:
  push:
    branches:
      - main

jobs:
  build:
    runs-on: ubuntu-latest

    steps:
      - name: Checkout code
        uses: actions/checkout@v2

      - name: Set up .NET
        uses: actions/setup-dotnet@v3
        with:
          dotnet-version: '8.0.x'

      - name: Restore dependencies
        run: dotnet restore

      - name: Build project
        run: dotnet build --configuration Release --no-restore

      - name: Publish project
        run: dotnet publish -c Release -o ./publish_output

      - name: Archive the app for transfer
        run: zip -r app.zip ./publish_output

      - name: SSH into EC2 and ensure directory exists
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EC2_PASSWORD }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            powershell -Command "New-Item -ItemType Directory -Force -Path 'C:\WebGroup\BirdProject'"

      - name: Transfer files to EC2 via SCP
        uses: appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.0
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EC2_PASSWORD }}
          port: 22
          source: "./app.zip"
          target: "C:/WebGroup/BirdProject"
          debug: true  # Enable detailed logging

      - name: SSH into EC2 and deploy
        uses: appleboy/ssh-action@v0.1.3
        with:
          host: ${{ secrets.EC2_HOST }}
          username: ${{ secrets.EC2_USER }}
          password: ${{ secrets.EC2_PASSWORD }}
          port: 22
          script: |
            powershell -Command "Expand-Archive -Path 'C:\WebGroup\BirdProject\app.zip' -DestinationPath 'C:\WebGroup\BirdProject\' -Force"
            powershell -Command "Restart-Service -Name 'w3svc'"


Previous steps of the script work as expected.
The user that is behind the variable has full permissions over the target path.
The error I get is the following:
Run appleboy/scp-action@v0.1.0
/usr/bin/docker run --name c605e00df8294b054418bad680eb2cf941ba0_b0f8aa --label 8c605e --workdir /github/workspace --rm -e "DOTNET_ROOT" -e "INPUT_HOST" -e "INPUT_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_PORT" -e "INPUT_SOURCE" -e "INPUT_TARGET" -e "INPUT_DEBUG" -e "INPUT_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_COMMAND_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_KEY" -e "INPUT_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "INPUT_RM" -e "INPUT_STRIP_COMPONENTS" -e "INPUT_OVERWRITE" -e "INPUT_TAR_TMP_PATH" -e "INPUT_PROXY_HOST" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PORT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USERNAME" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSWORD" -e "INPUT_PROXY_PASSPHRASE" -e "INPUT_PROXY_TIMEOUT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY" -e "INPUT_PROXY_KEY_PATH" -e "INPUT_PROXY_FINGERPRINT" -e "INPUT_PROXY_USE_INSECURE_CIPHER" -e "HOME" -e "GITHUB_JOB" -e "GITHUB_REF" -e "GITHUB_SHA" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_OWNER_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ID" -e "GITHUB_RUN_NUMBER" -e "GITHUB_RETENTION_DAYS" -e "GITHUB_RUN_ATTEMPT" -e "GITHUB_REPOSITORY_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR_ID" -e "GITHUB_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_TRIGGERING_ACTOR" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW" -e "GITHUB_HEAD_REF" -e "GITHUB_BASE_REF" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_NAME" -e "GITHUB_SERVER_URL" -e "GITHUB_API_URL" -e "GITHUB_GRAPHQL_URL" -e "GITHUB_REF_NAME" -e "GITHUB_REF_PROTECTED" -e "GITHUB_REF_TYPE" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_REF" -e "GITHUB_WORKFLOW_SHA" -e "GITHUB_WORKSPACE" -e "GITHUB_ACTION" -e "GITHUB_EVENT_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REPOSITORY" -e "GITHUB_ACTION_REF" -e "GITHUB_PATH" -e "GITHUB_ENV" -e "GITHUB_STEP_SUMMARY" -e "GITHUB_STATE" -e "GITHUB_OUTPUT" -e "RUNNER_OS" -e "RUNNER_ARCH" -e "RUNNER_NAME" -e "RUNNER_ENVIRONMENT" -e "RUNNER_TOOL_CACHE" -e "RUNNER_TEMP" -e "RUNNER_WORKSPACE" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RUNTIME_TOKEN" -e "ACTIONS_CACHE_URL" -e "ACTIONS_RESULTS_URL" -e GITHUB_ACTIONS=true -e CI=true -v "/var/run/docker.sock":"/var/run/docker.sock" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_home":"/github/home" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_github_workflow":"/github/workflow" -v "/home/runner/work/_temp/_runner_file_commands":"/github/file_commands" -v "/home/runner/work/BirdProject/BirdProject":"/github/workspace" 8c605e:00df8294b054418bad680eb2cf941ba0
tar all files into /tmp/482259334/YTYb89aCus.tar
$ tar -cf /tmp/482259334/YTYb89aCus.tar ./app.zip
scp file to server.
create folder C:/WebGroup/BirdProject
drone-scp error:  Process exited with status 1
drone-scp rollback: remove all target tmp file
remove file YTYb89aCus.tar
2024/09/07 16:47:55 Process exited with status 1

I have read that this way can only be used for linux docker, is that true? if that's the case how would be for a deployment to a EC2 server which runs a Windows 2022?
